# what happened to the palaces of Mahabharath?

Tags: mahabharata, history, geography

There were many huge palace in Dvapara Yuga according to Ramayana and Mahabharata. or e.g. Indraprastha or cities created By Vishwakarma. What happened to them? Why none of them exists now?

Comment: What palace are you referring?

Comment: I mean the huge buildings and castle our ancestors used to live

Comment: Well, Dwarka has been found on ocean bed of the West coast of Gujarat. I am sure if ASI does some digging, they will find many interesting things.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  If you want to focus your question on a particular palace rather than all of them, that may be more acceptable.  I suggest focusing on Indraprastha.